# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) Error in Linked List

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a C program to represent polynomial in linked list. Here is what I have done so far.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

struct poly
{
    float coef;
    int exp;
    struct poly* next;
};

void make(struct poly**, float, int);
void display(struct poly*);

void add(struct poly*, struct poly*, struct poly**);

int main()
{
    struct poly *first, *second, *final;
    int expa, expb, i;
    float data;

    first = second = final = NULL;

    printf("Enter maximum exponent for polynomial A ");
    scanf("%d", &expa);

    printf("Enter data for polynomial A\n");

    for(i=0;i<=expa;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter coefficient for exponent %d ", expa - i);
        scanf("%f", &data);

        make(&first, data, expa - i);
    }

    printf("Displaying polynomial A ");
    display(first);

    printf("Enter maximum exponent for polynomial B ");
    scanf("%d", &expb);

    printf("Enter data for polynomial B\n");

    for(i=0;i<=expb;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter coefficient for exponent %d ", expb - i);
        scanf("%f", &data);

        make(&second, data, expb - i);
    }

    printf("Displaying polynomial B ");
    display(second);

    printf("Now adding polynomials A and B \n");
    add(first, second, &final);

    display(final);
    return 1;
}

void make(struct poly**head, float coef, int exp)
{
    struct poly *new, *temp;

    new = (struct poly*)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
    new->coef = coef;
    new->exp = exp;
    new->next = NULL;
    temp = *head;

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        *head = new;
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = new;
}

void display(struct poly*head)
{
    struct poly*temp = head;

    while(temp)
    {
        printf("%.1fx^%d ", temp->coef, temp->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nExiting display\n");
}

void add(struct poly*first, struct poly*second, struct poly**sum)
{
    struct poly* new;
    printf("Currently in add");
    if(first == NULL && second == NULL)
        return;

    while(first&&second)
    {
        if((*sum)==NULL)
        {
            new = (struct poly*)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
            *sum = new;
        }
        else
        {
            new->next = (struct poly*)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
            new = new->next;
        }

        if(first->exp == second->exp)
        {
            new->exp = first->exp;
            new->coef = first->coef + second->coef;

            first = first->next;
            second = second ->next;
        }

        if(first->exp > second->exp)
        {
            new->exp = first->exp;
            new->coef = first->coef;
            first = first->next;
        }

        if(first->exp < second->exp)
        {
            new->exp = second->exp;
            new->coef = second->coef;
            second = second->next;
        }
        new->next = NULL;
    }

    while(first)
    {
        new->next = (struct poly*)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
        new->coef = first->coef;
        new->exp = first->exp;
        new->next = NULL;
        first = first->next;
    }

    while(second)
    {
        new->next = (struct poly*)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
        new->coef = second->coef;
        new->exp = second->exp;
        new->next = NULL;
        second= second->next;
    }
}

I am receiving output:
./PolynomialAdditionLinkedList.out 
Enter maximum exponent for polynomial A 2
Enter data for polynomial A
Enter coefficient for exponent 2 1
Enter coefficient for exponent 1 2
Enter coefficient for exponent 0 1
Displaying polynomial A 1.0x^2 2.0x^1 1.0x^0 
Exiting display
Enter maximum exponent for polynomial B 2
Enter data for polynomial B
Enter coefficient for exponent 2 1
Enter coefficient for exponent 1 6
Enter coefficient for exponent 0 9
Displaying polynomial B 1.0x^2 6.0x^1 9.0x^0 
Exiting display
Now adding polynomials A and B 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From the output, it looks like I have error in following line.
`add(first, second, &final);
As the output doesn't prints`Currently in add`, error occurs before it. I believe I haven't modified values of either first or second in any illegal way ?
Where am I making a mistake ?

Comment: Compile with debug information (add the `-g` flag to GCC or clang), and run your program in a debugger. It will stop at the crash, and you will be able to see the function call stack, and even walk up it to your code (if it's not already there) where you can examine variables. If you still can't figure it out, then edit your question to include the function call stack, pointing out where in your code that the crash happens.

Comment: probably you don't see the last `printf()` because it contains no `'\n'` and so it is still buffered when the seg fault occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `add` function you have this code:

```
if(first->exp == second->exp)
{
    new->exp = first->exp;
    new->coef = first->coef + second->coef;

    first = first->next;
    second = second ->next;
}

if(first->exp > second->exp)
{
    new->exp = first->exp;
    new->coef = first->coef;
    first = first->next;
}

if(first->exp < second->exp)
{
    new->exp = second->exp;
    new->coef = second->coef;
    second = second->next;
}
```

Now think for a second what happens when, in the first `if` statement, you are at the last node of one of the lists. That means that you will set `first` or `second` to `NULL`. Then what happens with the other `if` statements? You will dereference a `NULL` pointer!

What you want is an `if-else if` chain instead.

Comment: :I placed three continue statements in each of the if block. Would it have any effect on code performance if I had used if-else-if ladder instead ?

Comment: @hasH No, not really. As long as you don't forget to set `new->next` to `NULL` before the `continue` (best place is when you create the node).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the add() function a lot by removing repetition, merging common cases. The below function uses **goto** which is not as harmful as you might think:

```
struct poly *merge(struct poly *one, struct poly *two)
{
    struct poly *new,*result, **pp;
    fprintf(stderr, "Currently in merge\n");

    result=NULL;
    for(pp= &result; one || two; pp = &(*pp)->next ) {
       *pp = new = malloc (sizeof *new);
       new->next = NULL;
       if (!one) goto use_two;
       if (!two) goto use_one;
          /* when we get here, one and two are both non-null */
       if (one->exp > two->exp) goto use_one;
       if (one->exp < two->exp) goto use_two;
       if (one->exp == two->exp) goto use_both;

use_both: /* useless label for clarity */
       new->coef = one->coef + two->coef;
       new->exp = two->exp;
       two = two->next;
       one = one->next;
       continue;
use_two:
       new->coef = two->coef;
       new->exp = two->exp;
       two = two->next;
       continue;
use_one:
       new->coef = one->coef;
       new->exp = one->exp;
       one = one->next;
       continue;
       }

return result;
}
```

this should be called from main as:

```
    ...
    printf("Now adding polynomials A and B \n");
    // add(first, second, &final);
    final = merge (first, second);

    display(final);
    return 0; // <<-- main() should return 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS 
}
```

A few notes:

- I changed the function's signature, it now *returns* the created linked list of terms, instead of assigning it to a pointer-to-pointer passed as an argument
- You could try to replace the gotos and the three labels by a switch, or by inlined functions, or macros. The result will be a lot messier, and at least less compact.
- the *special cases* where one of the `one` or `two` lists are exhausted are now in the main loop. There are no special cases.
- thse *special case* where the first result node is assigned to `*head` is merged with the *normal case* (where `*head` is not NULL) just by moving `*pp` to the next place for insertion. Again: there are no special cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Since it has segfaulted and generated a core file, you could fire up gdb or your debugger of choice and see exactly where it crashed.

If you post that, it might help.

as Alter Mann pointed out, you use new uninitialised in add:

```
else
{
    new->next = (struct poly*)malloc(sizeof(struct poly));
```

if SUM is non -null, you go into this case, and on the first iteration new has not been allocated, and so you are dereferencing some random pointer. Which isnt NULL, since you dont initialise it, and so even if you did check new for NULL, it would likely still segfault.

```
void add(struct poly*first, struct poly*second, struct poly**sum)
{
    struct poly* new;
```

should be:

```
void add(struct poly*first, struct poly*second, struct poly**sum)
{
    struct poly* new=NULL;
```

This line does not check new, it checks sum.

```
if((*sum)==NULL)
{
```

EDIT: One last thought. You don't actually check that malloc succeded anywhere.

Comment: As I replied to Alter Mann, first if would be executed and then else would be executed making sure that new doesn't has `NULL` in else part. SUM would be NULL in first iteration as in main, it has been allocated NULL, which make sure that if part would execute first. As far as checking of sum for being NULL, it is intentional, I need to check if sum is NULL, if it is, it means I am at head of the list.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that the check on first and second is sane? eg  'if(first == NULL && second == NULL)'
        'return;' Did you mean || (or) instead of && (and)

Comment: And, did you run it in gdb to see where it crashes?

Comment: No. I figured out what was the problem. I had not used continue to move on after comparing their exponents. Answer that pointed me to it, has been marked accepted already.